# setViewControllers vs removeFromParentViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

We are building a journey where we need a View Controller to remove the Controller that came before it in the stack.

When we land on that View Controller it will be the 3rd controller in the stack and we need it to remove the Controller that is second (i.e. the Controller that is at index 1).

In ViewDidLoad we tried doing this by getting the current array of View Controllers from the Navigation Controller, removing the Controller at index 1 and then calling SetViewControllers. However when the back button is pressed we end up going back to the View Controller that was supposed to be removed.

If instead we call removeFromParentViewController on the View Controller to be removed then we get the behaviour we expected.

What are the differences between these two approaches? What would cause a View Controller to remain in the stack despite it not being in the array passed to SetViewControllers?

Comment: Are you sure modify the stack with `setViewControllers` didn't work? This code seems to do just that: https://pastebin.com/Zyp0KADZ

Comment: Yes, if the back button is pressed we end up on the view controller that was supposed to be removed. SetViewControllers is working in other scenarios so there must be something different about this flow.

Comment: Did you try running my sample code? When I run that, tapping "Push to Second VC" on (yellow) `FirstVC` pushes to (green) `SecondVC`. Tapping "Push to Third VC" then pushes to (cyan) `ThirdVC`. Then tapping the Back button takes me **back to (yellow) `FirstVC`** -- it does ***NOT*** go back to (green) `SecondVC`.

Comment: As I said that code also works for us in other situations in the app, but not for one particular flow. Our question is not whether or not setViewControllers is a solution but what would cause that not to work.

Comment: Difficult to say what could be causing it, without seeing the code. It's *possible* something has a strong reference... it's possible some other code is observing and re-adding the 2nd controller... I think you'll need to post a [mre] to get help with that.